# using c#5 async for non-blocking

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

If I have a web application that wraps calls to the network and database in a `Task<T>` and awaits them, this should prevent the thread from blocking so it can be re-used.

However, when the IO work is carried out, is there still some thread that is blocked, so there is no real benefit to awaiting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just wrapping blocking calls in a `Task.Run`, then you are correct: there is no benefit.

However, if you are using naturally-asynchronous methods (e.g., asynchronous `HttpClient`/`WebClient`/`HttpWebRequest` methods and asynchronous database methods), then no threads are used by those requests, and you get a scalability benefit.

At the device driver level of Windows, all I/O is asynchronous. The synchronous APIs are just convenience wrappers. Naturally-asynchronous methods do not block a thread over the synchronous APIs; they are built on the asynchronous APIs.

Comment: This information is scattered all over MSDN and various SDKs, but some good resources are Windows Internals and CLR via C#.